# Recaf: Recompile disabled, can't edit

Tags: java, decompiler, byte-code

I've download recaf jar file and install JDK 8. When I execute it/start it, it all works fine with `java -jar recaf-2.12.0-J8-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. I open a class file also no problem. The issue is when I try to edit it is disabled saying:

```
// =============================================== //
// Recompile disabled. Please run Recaf with a JDK //
// =============================================== //

// Decompiled with: CFR 0.150
...
```

Any idea why and how to solve this issue? This is my first time using recaf as well so it might be a newbie question.

Comment: Please do not report Recaf bugs outside of the GitHub issues pages. Most of the time I won't see them: https://github.com/Col-E/Recaf/issues

Also I believe this can be resolved by reading the doc pages: https://www.coley.software/Recaf/doc-setup-8.html

Comment: Like I mentioned in the issues on the the page I wasn't sure if it was a bug or not so also asked here to see if anyone else has had similar issues with solutions they found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. It is best if you report Recaf issues on the [Recaf github page](https://github.com/Col-E/Recaf), not a 3rd party platform
2. You **can still edit** but the recompilation feature is disabled due to the inability to find the local Java compiler. Most of Recaf is based on the assembler, which you can find documentation on here: ["Class editing modes"](https://www.coley.software/Recaf/doc-edit-modes.html)
3. This problem may still persist after a basic installation of Java 8 because the required platform tools are not added to the classpath. There is documentation on what files are required, where they are, and where you need to place them here: ["Java 8 setup"](https://www.coley.software/Recaf/doc-setup-8.html)
4. Alternatively you can update to Java 11 or higher where none of this configuration is necessary.

Comment: Tried 1-3 and didn't work. Point 4 helped thank you. I literally gave up on it for a bit.

Comment: @MarcoFernandes if you opened an issue on GitHub why you didn’t link to it?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I did it after posting it here first